# Make checkboxes filter using post or queries

Tags: jquery

```
<?php 

require "../connection.php";



$query= "Select * from meals where is_active= '1' AND category ='entree' ";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);

$query11= "Select * from meals where is_active= '1' AND category ='soup' ";
$result11=mysqli_query($conn,$query11);


$query21= "Select * from meals where is_active= '1' AND category ='bowl' ";
$result21=mysqli_query($conn,$query21);


$query31= "Select * from meals where is_active= '1' AND category ='salad' ";
$result31=mysqli_query($conn,$query31);     

$filters= "select * from meals LEFT JOIN meal_options ON meals.id = meal_options.meal_id LEFT JOIN main_filters ON meal_options.id = main_filters.meal_options_id where main_filters.vegan = 'N'";
$result_filter=mysqli_query($conn,$filters); ///THIS IS HOW I FILTER

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/style.css?v=<?php echo rand();?>">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/fonts.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="pageContent">

    <div id="OrderContainer">
        <div>
    <div id="OrderGetStarted1" class="new1" style="height:0px">
        <div class="started">
            <span class="block">
                <h1 class="textCenter OldStandard fontt">Hi <?php echo $firstname?>, Now comes the fun part!</h1>
        </span>
        </div>
        </div>

<div class="row rowing">
<form method="post">
  <div class="col-6 col-md-3 checkbox-rounds" id="filter-checks">
  <p class="orange OldStandard"> Menu Filters</p>
  <a type="button" class="check orange pointer OldStandard">Select All </a>
  <br>
  <a type="button" class="uncheck orange pointer OldStandard"> Unselect All</a>
  <br>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-round" value="vegan" id="vegan" checked/><label for="vegan" class="OldStandard"><span><i class="fa fa-circle"></i><i class="fa fa-check" ></i></span>Vegan</label>
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-round" value="vegetarian" id="vegetarian" checked/> <label for="vegetarian" class="OldStandard"><span><i class="fa fa-circle"></i><i class="fa fa-check" ></i></span>Vegetarian</label>
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-round" value="pescetarian" id="pescetarian" checked/> <label for="pescetarian" class="OldStandard"><span><i class="fa fa-circle"></i><i class="fa fa-check" ></i></span>Pescetarian</label>
         <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-round" value="dairy-free" id="dairy-free" checked/> <label for="dairy-free" class="OldStandard"><span><i class="fa fa-circle"></i><i class="fa fa-check" ></i></span>Dairy-free</label>
         <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-round" value="egg-free" id="egg-free" checked/> <label for="egg-free" class="OldStandard"><span><i class="fa fa-circle"></i><i class="fa fa-check" ></i></span>Egg-free</label>
         <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-round" value="fish-free" id="fish-free" checked/> <label for="fish-free" class="OldStandard"><span><i class="fa fa-circle"></i><i class="fa fa-check" ></i></span>Fish-free</label>
         <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-round" value="shellfish" id="shellfish" checked/> <label for="shellfish" class="OldStandard"><span><i class="fa fa-circle"></i><i class="fa fa-check" ></i></span> Shellfish-free</label>
          <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-round" value="tree" id="tree" checked/> <label for="tree" class="OldStandard"><span><i class="fa fa-circle"></i><i class="fa fa-check" ></i></span>Tree nut-free</label>
          <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-round" value="peanut" id="peanut" checked/> <label for="peanut" class="OldStandard"><span><i class="fa fa-circle"></i><i class="fa fa-check" ></i></span>Peanut-free</label>
          <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-round" value="soy" id="soy" checked/> <label for="soy" class="OldStandard"><span><i class="fa fa-circle"></i><i class="fa fa-check" ></i></span> Soy-free</label>
          <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-round" value="total-fat" id="total-fat" checked/> <label for="total-fat" class="OldStandard"><span><i class="fa fa-circle"></i><i class="fa fa-check" ></i></span> Low Total Fat</label>
          <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-round" value="saturated-fat" id="saturated-fat" checked/> <label for="saturated-fat" class="OldStandard"><span><i class="fa fa-circle"></i><i class="fa fa-check" ></i></span>Low Saturated Fat</label>
          <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-round" value="cholesterol" id="cholesterol" checked/> <label for="cholesterol" class="OldStandard"><span><i class="fa fa-circle"></i><i class="fa fa-check" ></i></span>Low Cholesterol</label>
          <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-round" value="sodium" id="sodium" checked/> <label for="sodium" class="OldStandard"><span><i class="fa fa-circle"></i><i class="fa fa-check" ></i></span>Low Sodium</label>
          <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-round" value="protein" id="protein" checked/> <label for="protein" class="OldStandard"> <span><i class="fa fa-circle"></i><i class="fa fa-check" ></i></span>Protein &#62;25g</label>
          <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-round" value="calories" id="calories" checked/> <label for="calories" class="OldStandard"><span><i class="fa fa-circle"></i><i class="fa fa-check" ></i></span>Calories  &#60;450 calories</label>
        <br>

  </div>
</form>

    <div class="col col-md-9" id="display_menu" style="margin-left:-80px;">
    <p class="orange OldStandard pull-left title_menu">Soups </p>  
        <button  class="disabled1 white cbtn1 pull-right" type="submit" id="submit" >Checkout  <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></button>



        <div class= "flex rowWrap foodDiv">

<?php while($row11 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result11)) {
    $name1=$row11['name'];
    $subtitle1=$row11['subtitle'];
    $image1=$row11['image_url'];
    $thumbnail1=$row11['thumb_url'];
    $meal_id1 = $row11['id'];

    $query12="select * from meal_options where meal_id = '$meal_id1'";
    $result12=mysqli_query($conn,$query12);


    $labels1=array();
    $prices1 =array();
    while($row12 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result12))
    {
        $label1= $row12['label'];
        $labels1[]= $label1;

        $price1= $row12['price'];
        $price1 = number_format($price1/100, 2);
        $price1 = "$" . $price1;
        $prices1[]= $price1;

    }

    $labels1=implode(" | ",$labels1);
    //$prices1 = implode(" - ", $prices1);
    $firstEle = $prices1[0];
    $lastEle = $prices1[count($prices1) - 1];
    //echo $firstEle ."-". $lastEle;die;

?>

                <span class="deliveryItem satin pointer vertical-top textCenter">
                 <img src="<?php echo $image1; ?>" width="250px" height= "200px;" class="foodImage">
                <div class="menuDelivery">
                <h3 class= "textCenter OldStandard dark-orange font1"> <?php echo $name1;?> </h3>
                <p class= "OldStandardItalic text-black font2"> <?php echo $subtitle1;?> </p>
                <hr>
                <span class="open_sansbold text-black">
                <?php   if(count($prices1) > 1){print_r($firstEle ."-". $lastEle);}
                else{ print_r($price1);}
                ?>
                <br>
                </span>
                <span class="text-black font2">
                <?php if(mysqli_num_rows($result12) >= 1){echo @$labels1;}  ?>

                <br>
                </span>
                <button  class="view white cbtn1 open_sansbold">View/Add</button>
                </div>
                </span>


                <?php }?>
        </div>  


            <p class="orange OldStandard pull-left title_menu">Bowls</p>  

                <div class= "flex rowWrap foodDiv">

<?php while($row21 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result21)) {
    $name21=$row21['name'];
    $subtitle21=$row21['subtitle'];
    $image21=$row21['image_url'];
    $thumbnail21=$row21['thumb_url'];
    $meal_id21 = $row21['id'];

    $query22="select * from meal_options where meal_id = '$meal_id21'";
    $result22=mysqli_query($conn,$query22);

    $labels22=array();
    $prices22 =array();
    while($row22 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result22))
    {
        $label22= $row22['label'];
        $labels22[]= $label22;

        $price22= $row22['price'];
        $price22 = number_format($price22/100, 2);
        $price22 = "$" . $price22;
        $prices22[]= $price22;

    }
    $labels22=implode(" | ",$labels22);
    //$prices22 = implode(" - ", $prices22);
    $firstEle22 = $prices22[0];
    $lastEle22 = $prices22[count($prices22) - 1];


?>

                <span class="deliveryItem satin pointer vertical-top textCenter">
                 <img src="<?php echo $image21; ?>" width="250px" height= "200px;" class="foodImage">
                <div class="menuDelivery">
                <h3 class= "textCenter OldStandard dark-orange font1"> <?php echo $name21;?> </h3>
                <p class= "OldStandardItalic text-black font2"> <?php echo $subtitle21;?> </p>
                <hr>
                <span class="open_sansbold text-black">
                <?php if(count($prices22) > 1){print_r($firstEle22 ."-". $lastEle22);}
                else{ print_r($price22);}?>
                <br>
                </span>
                <span class="text-black font2">
                <?php if(mysqli_num_rows($result22) >= 1){echo @$labels22;}  ?>

                <br>
                </span>
                <button  class="view white cbtn1 open_sansbold">View/Add</button>
                </div>
                </span>


                <?php }?>
        </div>





<p class="orange OldStandard pull-left title_menu">Salad</p>  

                <div class= "flex rowWrap foodDiv">

<?php while($row31 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result31)) {
    $name31=$row31['name'];
    $subtitle31=$row31['subtitle'];
    $image31=$row31['image_url'];
    $thumbnail31=$row31['thumb_url'];
    $meal_id31 = $row31['id'];

    $query32="select * from meal_options where meal_id = '$meal_id31'";
    $result32=mysqli_query($conn,$query32);

    $labels32=array();
    $prices32 =array();
    while($row32 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result32))
    {
        $label32= $row32['label'];
        $labels32[]= $label32;

        $price32= $row32['price'];
        $price32 = number_format($price32/100, 2);
        $price32 = "$" . $price32;
        $prices32[]= $price32;

    }
    $labels32=implode(" | ",$labels32);
    //$prices32 = implode(" - ", $prices32);
    $firstEle32 = $prices32[0];
    $lastEle32 = $prices32[count($prices32) - 1];


?>

                <span class="deliveryItem satin pointer vertical-top textCenter">
                 <img src="<?php echo $image31; ?>" width="250px" height= "200px;" class="foodImage">
                <div class="menuDelivery">
                <h3 class= "textCenter OldStandard dark-orange font1"> <?php echo $name31;?> </h3>
                <p class= "OldStandardItalic text-black font2"> <?php echo $subtitle31;?> </p>
                <hr>
                <span class="open_sansbold text-black">
                <?php if(count($prices32) > 1){print_r($firstEle32 ."-". $lastEle32);}
                else{ print_r($price32);}?>
                <br>
                </span>
                <span class="text-black font2">
                <?php if(mysqli_num_rows($result32) >= 1){echo @$labels32;}  ?>

                <br>
                </span>
                <button  class="view white cbtn1 open_sansbold">View/Add</button>
                </div>
                </span>


                <?php }?>
        </div>










        <p class="orange OldStandard pull-left title_menu">Entr&#233;es</p>  

                <div class= "flex rowWrap foodDiv">

<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $name=$row['name'];
    $subtitle=$row['subtitle'];
    $image=$row['image_url'];
    $thumbnail=$row['thumb_url'];
    $meal_id = $row['id'];

    $query2="select * from meal_options where meal_id = '$meal_id'";
    $result2=mysqli_query($conn,$query2);

    $labels=array();
    $prices =array();
    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2))
    {
        $label= $row2['label'];
        $labels[]= $label;

        $price= $row2['price'];
        $price = number_format($price/100, 2);
        $price = "$" . $price;
        $prices[]= $price;

    }
    $labels=implode(" | ",$labels);
    //$prices = implode(" - ", $prices);
    $firstEle1 = $prices[0];
    $lastEle1 = $prices[count($prices) - 1];


?>

                <span class="deliveryItem satin pointer vertical-top textCenter">
                 <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" width="250px" height= "200px;" class="foodImage">
                <div class="menuDelivery">
                <h3 class= "textCenter OldStandard dark-orange font1"> <?php echo $name;?> </h3>
                <p class= "OldStandardItalic text-black font2"> <?php echo $subtitle;?> </p>
                <hr>
                <span class="open_sansbold text-black">
                <?php if(count($prices) > 1){print_r($firstEle1 ."-". $lastEle1);}
                else{ print_r($price);};?>
                <br>
                </span>
                <span class="text-black font2">
                <?php if(mysqli_num_rows($result2) >= 1){echo @$labels;}  ?>

                <br>
                </span>
                <button  class="view white cbtn1 open_sansbold">View/Add</button>
                </div>
                </span>


                <?php }?>
        </div>  


    </div>
</div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.check').click(function() {
          $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", true);
        });

        $('.uncheck').click(function() {
          $('input:checkbox').prop("checked", false);
          $(".chk-btn").hide();

        });     
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried adding this to the query:

```
while($row_filter = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_filter)){
    $vegan = $row_filter['vegan'];
    $vegetarian = $row_filter['vegetarian'];
    $pescetarian = $row_filter['pescetarian'];
    $tree = $row_filter['tree nut-free'];
    $peanut = $row_filter['peanut-free'];
    $soy = $row_filter['soybean-free'];
    $total = $row_filter['low-total-fat'];
    $dairy = $row_filter['dairy-free'];
    $egg = $row_filter['egg-free'];
    $fish = $row_filter['fish-free'];
    $shellfish = $row_filter['shellfish'];
    $saturated = $row_filter['low-saturated-fat'];
    $cholesterol = $row_filter['low-cholesterol'];
    $sodium = $row_filter['low-sodium'];
    $protein = $row_filter['protein(25g)'];
    $calories = $row_filter['calories(450)'];
```

And on the span I write an if statement saying it vegan ="Y", echo "vegan", so it will be a class, that is the same name as the value of the checkbox but it didn't work, can anyone show me how this is done?
I'm a bit stuck and really confused.

Comment: please define "didn't work". What happens instead? What output do you get? And I can't actually see the code you mention anywhere in your sample. Where are you writing this if statement?

Comment: Inside each span @ADyson

Comment: you said "_on the span I write an if statement saying it vegan ="Y", echo "vegan"_". There are over 60 spans in your code sample, but I can't see any which contain any such "if" statement pertaining to Vegan. Also there is so much code here, it cannot all be relevant to your problem. Please see this article and create just a minimal example which contains enough information to reproduce your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. It will make it much easier to understand what you mean.